# How to change object's property value in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following problem :

```js
var a = {
    'a': '',
    'b': ''
},

b = [1,3],
o = {};

for (i = 0; i<b.length; i++) {
    o['shop' + b[i]] = a;
    o['shop' + b[i]].store = b[i];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Expecting shop[n] will be equal to store value, but it's wrong

```
{
    "shop1" : {
        "a" : "",
        "b" : "",
        "store":3
    },
    "shop3" : {
        "a" : "",
        "b" : "",
        "store":3
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: what do u mean by "store value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a single object to which `a` refers and when changing it via each iteration you actually change the value for all of them, because you work with the reference which refers to the single object. You can use [**Object destructing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to copy the object for each property in the `o`.

```js
var a = {
    'a': '',
    'b': ''
};
var b = [1,3];
var o = {};

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    o['shop' + b[i]] = {...a};
    o['shop' + b[i]].store = b[i];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Comment: I don't understand how to fix it. If I redefine it var aa = a, it doesn't work too.

Comment: You need to copy the actual object to which `a` refers - into another object which `{ ...a }` does.
`var aa = a` is just another reference to the actual object. I think you need to look at objects and how they are stored in the memory

Comment: Worth noting that Object destructing has a quite limited support at the current state.

Comment: Instead you can use `Object.assign`